# Query working normally but not working in prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following code of a prepared statement

```
// Get the data about the file
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM file WHERE generated_name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $generated_name);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->num_rows == 0) return 'Error';
```

The code above is not working, it's always returning an error even though it shouldn't affected_rows is weirdly returning -1 as well. However, if I leave the prepared approach and do a normal query.. it works perfectly

```
// Get the data about the file
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM file WHERE generated_name = '$generated_name'");
if($result->num_rows == 0) return 'Error';
```

This code works perfectly and doesn't return an error. I have no idea what is wrong. Could you please identify the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use store_result after execute

```
$stmt->store_result();
$rows= $stmt->num_rows;
if($rows > 0)...
```

Comment: this is not supported on some php installations, such as HipHopVirtualMachine, which also doesn't support get_result() either

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to do the "fetch" to actually get the rows; http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Try adding this;

```
   $stmt->fetch();
```

like this;

```
// Get the data about the file
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM file WHERE generated_name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $generated_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();
if($stmt->num_rows == 0) return 'Error';
```

Comment: might be helpful to explain the reason you have to call `fetch()`, because remember you must optionaly `bind_result()` after `execute()` to bind results to variables. if it automatically fetched the result you wouldn't have the chance to bind variables.

Comment: good point r3wt, you'll want to use bind_result if you plan to actually get the data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php#71988) comment about `num_rows` in PHP manual explains it. Quote:

> If you do not use mysqli_stmt_store_result( ), and immediatley call
>   this function after executing a prepared statement, this function will
>   usually return 0 as it has no way to know how many rows are in the
>   result set as the result set is not saved in memory yet.